# ASP.NET authentication for custom API

Tags: php, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I know this is a pretty discussed topic but i'm struggling in finding a solution for my case.

I have done an already working **API service** in `ASP.NET (c# 4.5.1)`. My clients uses **php pages** to call a **page.aspx** on my server and sending via POST a string. This string contains an **ID and a cypher message**. Every user have a different key (AES 256) and, since i have the ID i get from my DB the correct key to decypher the message and do what its request contains. I also check the IP, every client have only a list of **approved IPs** (when they are not using the debug mode for testing)

I like this method but now i have to let my users do some purchases. I already implemented it (thank you PayPal) and it works, but i feel my security *weak*.

So i wanted to add some **already known** and **already wrapped** authentication system, **without re-writing** any of the already working and debugged code.

Since is used from lot of big internet services i thought about `OAuth 2.0` (and *i know nothing* about it), but looks like everyone who talks about it is for creating a login that uses services like *Facebook, Google, Twitter* and go on.. not my case. I have **my own database** with **my user list** and i need to know with 100% security who is calling my API service.

I tried creating a new Web API 2 project (MVC.. damn) but i cannot understand if i can use for my service without rewriting the logic for API calling (and from what i saw looks like **no** is the answer)

So the question is: What authentication method can i use that is **easy to implement** without rewriting the **already working code** and can be usable from clients with **PHP**?

Comment: What's with all the *bold*...

Answer (score 1):

I was watching "ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals" tutorial on Pluralsight by Scott Allen where he explains it quite nicely. But before watching that tutorial, for one App I worked on, we had a table in the database with tokens that were issues at Login. Then the client would send the token with their request. At server side, I did a custom attribute called [CheckToken] inside which I would check if the token exists in the database and if it is stil valid (not expired, etc.) I went a step further and sometimes swap the token so that even if the token gets stolen, it would not be valid for long. That way, the user does not have to keep login in all the time.